# Creating custom Exceptions that Django reacts to

Tags: django

For my site I created an abstract Model which implements model-level read permissions.  That part of the system is completed and works correctly.  One of the methods the permissioned model exposes is `is_safe(user)` which can manually test if a user is allowed to view that model or not.

What I would like to do is add a method to the effect of `continue_if_safe` which can be called on any model instance, and instead of returning a boolean value like `is_safe` it would first test if the model can be viewed or not, then in the case of False, it would redirect the user, either to the login page if they aren't already logged in or return a 403 error if they are logged in.

**Ideal usage:**

```
model = get_object_or_404(Model, slug=slug)
model.continue_if_safe(request.user)
# ... remainder of code to be run if it's safe down here ...
```

I peeked at how the get_object_or_404 works, and it throws an `Http404` error which seems to make sense.  However, the problem is that there don't seem to be equivalent redirect or 403 errors.  What's the best way to go about this?

**(non-working) continue_if_safe method:**

```
def continue_if_safe(self, user):

    if not self.is_safe(user):
        if user.is_authenticated():
            raise HttpResponseForbidden()
        else:
            raise HttpResponseRedirect('/account/')

    return
```

---

### Edit -- The Solution

The code for the final solution, in case other "stackers" need some help with this:

**In the Abstract Model:**

```
def continue_if_safe(self, user):
    if not self.is_safe(user):
        raise PermissionDenied()
    return
```

**Views are caught by the middleware:**

```
class PermissionDeniedToLoginMiddleware(object):
    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        if type(exception) == PermissionDenied:
            if not request.user.is_authenticated():
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/account/?next=' + request.path)
        return None
```

**Usage in the view (very short and sweet):**

```
model = get_object_or_404(Model, slug=slug)
model.continue_if_safe(request.user)
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to update this question with details.  I completely misunderstood it beforehand.  I appreciate it!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For the forbidden (403) error, you could raise a `PermissionDenied` exception (from `django.core.exceptions`).

For the redirecting behaviour, there's no built-in way to deal with it the way you describe in your question. You could write a custom middleware that will catch your exception and redirect in [`process_exception`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/#process-exception).

Comment: Between the time I first read your answer and when you edited it I did just what you recommended (in your edit).  It seems to be working great.

Comment: if you raise PermissionDenied then Django will display the contents of templates/403.html, if it exists.

Comment: @scytale it will do so (and still with a 403 status code) at the handler level, except if `process_exception` on a middleware returns an `HttpResponse`

Answer (score 5):

I've made a little middleware that return whatever your Exception class's render method returns. Now you can throw custom exception's (with render methods) in any of your views.

```
class ProductNotFound(Exception):
    def render(self, request):
        return HttpResponse("You could ofcourse use render_to_response or any response object")
```

---

```
pip install -e git+http://github.com/jonasgeiregat/django-excepted.git#egg=django_excepted
```

And add `django_excepted.middleware.ExceptionHandlingMiddleware` to your `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`.

Comment: Does not handle exceptions from everywhere: https://github.com/jonasgeiregat/django-excepted/issues/3

Answer (score 2):

Django annoying has a solution for this:

```
from annoying.exceptions import Redirect

...
    raise Redirect('/')  # or a url name, etc
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use decorators for this. Look up `login_required` for an example. Basically the decorator will allow you check check the safety and then **return** `HttpResponseRedirect()` if its not safe.

Your code will end up looking something like this:

```
@safety_check:
def some_view(request):
    #Do Stuff
```

Comment: But the safety check is relative to the *query* not the *user*, which makes this pattern rather difficult, don't you think?  It's not a matter of if the user has permission to see the view, it's a matter of which records within the view they have access to.

Comment: You would be able to do that check in the decorator function.